# Контроллеры в kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

**Вопросы**

- С pods может работать одновременно ReplicaSet Controller и Deployment Controller?
- C ключами пода в etcd может работать Deployment Controller и ReplicaSet Controller?

**Комментарий**
Я выясняю связи внутри k8s (Kubernetes). Как controllers друг с другом работают и с какими resources. Почему pods могут управлять Deployment Controller и ReplicaSet Controller. Это потенциально усложняет их внутреннюю структуру и логику работы.

На мой взгляд было бы логичнее иметь либо Deployment-ReplicaSet Controller, либо добавить Pod Controller

Answer (score 0):

Основное назначение контроллера ReplicaSet - это поддержание указанного количества запущенных подов. Если посмотреть [исходный код](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/aab9a7c26257c0c123a3b2edc62b65b0cd585e10/pkg/controller/replicaset/replica_set.go#L173) контроллера, то можно увидеть, что он подписывается на события создания, обновления и удаления Pod. Основная логика по управлению подами представлена в методе `manageReplicas`, где происходит вычисление актуального количества подов и желаемого. Если есть разница, то создаются новые поды или удаляются лишние.

Deployment - это абстракция на уровень выше, которая позволяет, например, использовать разные стратегии деплоя (RollingUpdate, Recreate), просматривать историю деплоя, делать откаты и т.д. Контроллер Deployment уже управляет напрямую не Pod, а ReplicaSet, чтобы получить желаемое число подов в кластере. Если посмотреть [исходный код](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/c3e3ff989ac9abfb0dc3b958fcb698fcce952f8c/pkg/controller/deployment/deployment_controller.go#L140), то контроллер подписывается только на события удаления Pod, чтобы реализовать логику стратегии Recreate, но напрямую управляет ресурсом ReplicaSet, а не подами.

Рассматривайте эти сущности как кирпичики, поверх которых выстраивается более сложная логика, что позволяет переиспользовать готовую функциональность: Deployment -> ReplicaSet -> Pod. Вы, например, можете написать свою логику по деплою подов в собственном контроллере и переиспользовать ReplicaSet.

> C ключами пода в etcd может работать Deployment Controller и ReplicaSet Controller?

Отвечая формально, то с etcd работает только один компонент Kubernetes - kube-apiserver, проводя аутентификацию, авторизацию, валидацию запросов и в конечном итоге меняя состояние объекта в etcd.

Comment: Давай поделим по доменам. Через kubeapi взамоидействуют все со всеми